# llenar combobox desde un archivo txt java

Tags: java, array, netbeans, txt

Consulta. Tengo un archivo estado.txt, dentro de el existe data como ACTIVO, INACTIVO,CESADO y quiero llenarlo en un `JComboBox` ya que luego quiero modificar el archivo y agregar mas opciones y estos se carguen, sin necesidad de agregarlos en el código mismo. es posible esto?, es solo un archivo txt plano.

Quiero tomar el primer valor de cada fila, e ir agregando al `JComboBox`.

Este es mi codigo pero no se como jalar esta información a un `JComboBox`.

```
try {
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("estado.txt"));
  String linea;
  while((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(linea,",");
  }
  br.close();
} catch(Exception x) {
  x.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow! Te invito a leer lo siguiente: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Esta comunidad resuelves dudas especificas, no realiza pedidos de códigos. Por lo tanto, te recomiendo editar tu pregunta, en la cual, agregues el código que tengas hecho y especifiques en detalle, cual es tu duda.

Comment: Bienvenido modifica tu pregunta en base al documento [ask], saludos!

Comment: declaras tu tokenizador, pero nunca lo usas.... seguro que no es ese el problema?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
          BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("estado.txt"));
          String linea;
          JComboBox<String> combo=new JComboBox<String>();
          while((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(linea,",");
            System.out.println(tokens.nextElement());
            combo.addItem(tokens.nextToken());

          }
          br.close();
        } catch(Exception x) {
          x.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Solo agrega el token en el comboBox

Comment: lo que sucede es que mi comboBox se encuentra en un Frame y mi método cargar() en otro Arreglo, he intentando con llamarlo desde el Frame pero  me genera un error y no compila o no muestra nada, Necesariamente debo crear mi método y mi Array en el Frame para que funcione?

Answer (score 0):

public  void CargarN(JComboBox cbo){

```
            try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Perfumes.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        
        String linea;
        String nom;
        
        while((linea = br.readLine()) != null ){
            String s[] = linea.split(";");
            
             nom=s[1].trim();
       
           cbo.addItem(nom);
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Beto ERROR:" + e);
    }
    
}
```